# Make partial mock of class with Jest in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I have a function `extractPayloadDates` which accept an instance of dialogflow `Agent` and taking and parsing data from it. I want to mock only single method `getParameter` of `Agent`, because no more methods are used in the tested function. I found this code online but it doesn't work

```
import { Agent } from '../../src/dialogflow/Agent';
import { extractPayloadDates } from '../../src/intents/extractPayloadDates';

describe('extractPayloadDates', () => {
  it('tests extracting string', () => {
    const AgentMock = jest.fn<Agent, []>(() => ({
      getParameter: () => {
        return 'some date';
      }
    }));
    const agent = new AgentMock();

    expect(extractPayloadDates(agent)).toEqual('some date');
  });
});
```

This code produce following error:

> Type '{ getParameter: () => string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Agent': payload, webhookClient, chatter, getOriginalRequest, and 13 more.ts(2740)
> index.d.ts(124, 53): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.

I also tried to use `jest.spyOn`, but the problem is, that I cannot create Agent instance as it needs many other objects.

---

## Edit 3.9.2019 with more code

**Agent.ts**

```js
export class Agent {
  private payload: DialogFlowPayload[] = [];

  constructor(readonly webhookClient: WebhookClient, private readonly chatter: Chatter) {}
...
}
```

**WebhookClient** and **Chatter** have more dependencies in their constructor as well...

**extractPayloads.spec.ts**

```js
import { Agent } from '../../src/dialogflow/Agent';
import { extractPayloadDates } from '../../src/intents/extractPayloadDates';

describe('extractPayloadDates', () => {
  it('tests extracting string', () => {
    const webhookMock = jest.fn();
    const chatter = jest.fn();
    const agent = new Agent(webhookMock, chatter);

    expect(extractPayloadDates(agent)).toEqual('some date');
  });
});
```

This produce another error:

> Argument of type 'Mock<any, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Chatter'.
> Property 'getMessage' is missing in type 'Mock<any, any>' but required in type 'Chatter'

Do I really have to create also WebhookClient and all its dependencies and do the same with Chatter? If I do, I have to create instances of multiple classes just to mock 1 method in Agent, which then will not use any of dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs of jest

> If you want to overwrite the original function, you can use jest.spyOn(object, methodName).mockImplementation(() => customImplementation) or object[methodName] = jest.fn(() => customImplementation);

`jest.spyOn` call `jest.fn` internally. So you can only mock `getParameter` method of agent like this:

`extractPayloadDates.ts`:

```
function extractPayloadDates(agent) {
  return agent.getParameter();
}

export { extractPayloadDates };
```

`Agent.ts`:

```
interface DialogFlowPayload {}
interface WebhookClient {}
interface Chatter {
  getMessage(): any;
}
class Agent {
  private payload: DialogFlowPayload[] = [];

  constructor(readonly webhookClient: WebhookClient, private readonly chatter: Chatter) {}

  public getParameter() {
    return 'real data';
  }

  public otherMethod() {
    return 'other real data';
  }
}

export { Agent, Chatter };
```

Unit test, only mock `getParameter` method of `agent`, keep the original implementation of `otherMethod`

```
import { extractPayloadDates } from './extractPayloadDates';
import { Agent, Chatter } from './Agent';

const webhookMock = jest.fn();
const chatter: jest.Mocked<Chatter> = {
  getMessage: jest.fn()
};

const agent = new Agent(webhookMock, chatter);

describe('extractPayloadDates', () => {
  it('should only mock getParameter method of agent', () => {
    agent.getParameter = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce('mocked data');
    const actualValue = extractPayloadDates(agent);
    expect(actualValue).toEqual('mocked data');
    expect(agent.otherMethod()).toBe('other real data');
  });
});
```

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57428542/extractPayloadDates.spec.ts
  extractPayloadDates
    ✓ should only mock getParameter method of agent (7ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.484s, estimated 3s
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. However not sure if I understand.. I cannot do `new Agent()` because Agent has many other dependencies. Or should I create another Agent.ts which is just class for mocking?

Comment: @Arxeiss You can mock the dependencies and inject them to the constructor of `Agent`. That's why code use dependency Injection is easy to test. Update the answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I still can't make it work. Trying to mock also dependencies. But typescript complains about it doesn't match same type. I will provide more code into my original question.

Comment: Thank you, but it shows now `Property 'Mocked' does not exists on type 'typeof jest'. Did you mean 'mock'?`. However I cannot find anything about Mocked somewhere in documentation. Maybe it has some replacement? Or I have wrong dependencies? `@types/jest@23.3.14`, `jest@24.7.1` and `ts-jest@24.0.2`

Comment: @Arxeiss It's probably. Check the demo here: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57428542

Comment: I found a problem... I just typed it badly. However they added multiple methods into Chatter and I have to mock all of them. This is really needed? Now there are another 6 methods and I have to assign jest.fn() into every single one. And with WebhookClient I would need to do the same? 
However you answered to my original question

Comment: @Arxeiss Yes. I understand you want the partial mocked method types, you don't need mock all the methods. Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57772973/6463558

Comment: Thank you... So basically withou that __utils file which you probably coded yourself, there is no way to create partial mock just with jest. You have to do utility to handle this. Am I right?

Comment: @Arxeiss Yes. There is a GitHub issue link in the answer. It seems this feature has been merged, but I think it's not documented. Jestjs support partial mock, but we are talking about how to add typescript partial mock type definition for it. That's why the __utils file come.